# How do I properly log a Firebase analytics event with information entered in a textfield

Tags: swift, firebase-analytics

I've been looking at the docs and understand that to log an event such as when a user clicks on a button in Swift, you would enter something like 
`Analytics.logEvent("add", parameters: nil)` and Analytics would count the number of times the button was pressed.

Is it possible to track the value someone enters into a textfield and Firebase or Google Analytics displays that information? This is where I don't know if I'm doing it right:
`Analytics.logEvent("add_unit", parameters: ["unitAmount": Double])`

If I wanted to track that someone entered 1.5 units, `add_unit` will count *1* and `unitAmount` should show *1.5* in my Events dashboard?

I've tried the above and Analytics did track the *add_unit* count but did not display the value in my Events.

**TL:DR** 1) Did I enter the parameters properly and 2) If it was entered properly, where on my Analytics page do I see the 1.5 value that was entered?